# How to compile Linux C program to run on another Linux machine?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, version

I am using a VPS to host my website, but the gcc package is not installed. The libc.so.6 is mapped to libc-2.12.so and this is my problem, because on my home computer the library is mapped to libc-2.15.so

From time to time, I need to run some programs on VPS, so when I compile the C sources I use the -static option to include in the executable file everything is needed. The program works fine, but it bothers me that executable is about 800 Kb. If I compile without using -static option, executable is about 80 Kb, but it doesn't work on VOS.

Does anybody know any other solution to compile without using -static option, such that the executable be smaller ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Build a chroot containing the same libraries and executables as on the other machine, and perform the build in there.

Comment: Sure, if that floats your boat.